# in talend tftpget is not retriving duplicate images why?

Tags: talend

[image: 1778 images done]

but in [image: Actual folder where images are stored]
only 689 images are there I understand that It is not get the same image if it's already in folder. 
but I don't understand why?
Can anybody explained me?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which values are being used in your job you can use a `Debug run`. Just make sure to enable the traces you wish to inspect. The traces look like a small magnifying glass with a green plus icon on top:

[image]

Use right click and *enable / disable* to set only the connections you need to be traced. Now every value is being displayed.

Alternatively, on **row1** you can add a **tLogRow** component and inspect all values. Then you can find out if something happens you didn't expect.